# GUI Telnet Client to execute predefined commands

Tags: linux, vb.net, ssh, telnet, putty

Im trying to find if there is a utility exists which provides GUI for telnet client. The tool should provide a interface where I could provide Username and Password and few command buttons when execute sends some commands to the telnet server.

Can Putty/Webmin/Bitvise any could solve this or can it be developed using VB scripts?